# wp_enqueue_scripts leads to error

Tags: php, javascript, genesis-theme-framework

I am adding a javascript file by hooking into wp_enqueue_scripts(). Here's the code:

```
function order_tracking() {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->ID == 19851 ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('ordertracking', get_template_directory_uri(), array('jquery') ,'1.0', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'order_tracking' );
```

The javascript file contains a simple code:

```
/**
 * test javascript function
 */

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('loaded');
    jQuery("#ordertrackingsubmit").on("click", function (e) {
        var quotenum = jQuery("#quotenum").val();
        console.log(quotenum);
    }); 
});
```

But I am seeing errors. On the Google Chrome console, it says the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'     ?ver=1.0:1
```

One the sources tab, it says the following:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function genesis() in /home/skirting/public_html/alcocovers.com/wp-content/themes/genesis/index.php:15
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/skirting/public_html/alcocovers.com/wp-content/themes/genesis/index.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? When I add the code directly into `footer.php` the code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a genesis child theme so had to edit my `order_tracking()` function a little. `get_template_directory_uri()` gives the URL to the current **child** theme, combining that with the javascript filename did the trick.

Here's what got it working:

```
function order_tracking() {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->ID == 19851 ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('ordertracking', get_template_directory_uri(). "/ordertracking.js", array('jquery') ,'1.0', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'order_tracking' );
```